# r bookdown epub table caption issue

Tags: r, markdown, epub, bookdown

The generation of the epub option for bookdown is not making table captions correctly.  Every table has the markdown label also showing in the table caption. This occurs for tables that are basic markdown tables and tables that are generated from kable in a knit chunk.  Here is an example output. As you can see, the reference in the text is good, but the caption should read Table 2.4: Time of arrivals and service times for 8 customer.  But, instead, it is showing the chunk label (#tab:ArrServTime).  The PDF output does not have this problem, nor does the HTML output. It is occurring only in the epub ouput.  Since this is occurring in every table, I am wondering if this is a bug or some configuration option that I am missing.

Has anyone else experienced this issue?  Is there a work around?

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a bug of bookdown. Could you file a report to https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues? Thanks!